# extract keyword from a column to a new column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I tried to extract keywords from an existing column to become values in a new column so I can do some groupby operation for further analysis. I've done some researches here and there but I cannot find the solutions yet.

The current dataframe looks like below with say 10K lines, and I've already convert all entries under col Finding Title to lowercase:

| Entity | Finding Title |
| --- | --- |
| Singapore | usb port blocking not implemented |
| UK | servers using outdated windows server os version |

My expected output:

| Entity | Finding Title | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Singapore | usb port blocking not implemented | usb port |
| UK | servers using outdated windows server os version | outdated windows |

My code is like below:

```
key_word = ['data protection agreement', 'disaster recovery plan', 'hard drive encryption', 'inappropriate access','network', 
        'rule management', 'backup', 'fire', 'password', 'server room', 
        'outdated window', 'usb', 'user policy']

df['Key'] = df['Finding Title'].str.extractall(key_word)
```

The it return the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Appreciate your suggestions as always. Thank you and stay safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
df['Key'] = df['Finding Title'].str.findall('|'.join(key_word))
```

But this will give you a list as the output. Something like [usb], [outdated window]. I don't know if there is a better way, but you can get string output by joining it again. By adding this code below.

```
df["Key"]= df["Key"].str.join(", ")
```

So it is something like this :

```
df['Key'] = df['Finding Title'].str.findall('|'.join(key_word))
df["Key"]= df["Key"].str.join(", ")
```

By joining it using comma, you also can anticipated if there are 2 keywords or more (USB, outdated window).

Comment: Thanks, the solution .str.join(', ') works for my case.

Comment: Same scenario, but I want unrepeated list of words only in the new column. That is, if a word is occuring more than once, I want that word only once in the new column.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding, you did not want a word to appear twice in the column. If that is the problem, you can just check if the word is already exist in the column right?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
df['Key'] = df['Finding Title'].str.findall('|'.join(key_word))
```

Comment: Thank for your comment. I tried this already and it returns value wrapped with ' [ ] '. When I perform groupby operation on it, it throw me the same error  "unhashable type: 'list' "